# Error in guard condition while combining a list and single item

Tags: haskell, guard

I am trying to add the head of the list (`r`) to the list `sack`, however I keep getting this error message.

```
ERROR "Knapsack.hs":35 - Type error in guarded expression
*** Term           : findItems rt (r : sack) (getTotalWeight sack r)
*** Type           : [Item]
*** Does not match : [[Item]]
```

The code is listed below.

```
findItems :: [Item] -> [Item] -> Float -> [Item]
findItems (r:rt) sack total 
            | total > 20 = [sack]
            | canContinue = findItems rt (r : sack ) (getTotalWeight sack r) 
            | otherwise = [sack] 
            where canContinue = (getTotalWeight sack r) < 20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot return `[sack]` from `findItems`, because `sack` is already of type `[Item]`, so `[sack]` is of type `[[Item]]`. Remove the brackets.

The reason the message complains about the *second* case (which does return `[Item]` as it should) is probably (I'm guessing here) that Haskell expects all cases to be of the same type, so it checks that they're all of the same type as the first, which incorrectly happens to be `[[Item]]`. This checking appears to happen before it even tries to reconcile the type of the `|` expression with the type of `findItems`. Haskell gurus will probably be able to correct me on the finer points here :)

Comment: Thank you so much, i am new to Haskell and made that mistake earlier on and did not think that was the problem.

Comment: If you try to compile it with GHC, you get `Couldn't match expected type \`Item' with actual type \`[Item]'` for `[sack]`. Which error message you get depends on the implementation of the type checking algorithm. Hugs does it different from GHC.

Comment: A general property of automatic type inference is that when there _is_ a type error, it's often not at all obvious exactly _where_ the error is. So different compilers and interpreters will point at differnet parts of the code.

Answer (score 3):

What you have run into appears to be a "Hugs-ism", where Hugs seems to do its type-checking in a different way than GHC. If you plug the same code into GHCi you will get an error pointing to the line that actually contains it:

```
| total > 20 = [sack]
```

In this case it appears GHCi is generating better error messages (although, IMHO, typically they can be more cryptic than need be!).